# How to set up a Spring web service without using any XML files?

Tags: spring, configuration, annotations, jax-ws

It seems to me that, even if I use a @Configuration class to wire all the beans, the web service part of Spring will still require some configuration in an XML file. Does anyone know how to set up a Spring web service without any XML files?

At this point it doesn't matter if it's JAXWS or SpringWS, as long as it just work.

I'm using Spring 3.1.2 with JAX-WS 2.2.3. This is what I have so far:

```
//The endpoint
@WebService(serviceName = "EquityService")
public class EquityServiceEndPoint extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport implements EquityService {

    @Autowired
    private EquityService equityService;

    @WebMethod
    public String helloWorld() {
        return equityService.helloWorld();
    }

}
```

This is the configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class MarketServerConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public EquityService equityService() {
        return new EquityServiceImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public EquityServiceEndPoint equityServiceEndPoint() {
        return new EquityServiceEndPoint();
    }

}
```

And this is the web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
     version="2.4">

    <display-name>MarketService</display-name>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>com.hello.market.server.MarketServerConfiguration</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jaxws-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSSpringServlet
        </servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jaxws-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/service/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

I run the whole thing with Jetty. When I go to http:// localhost:8888/service I get a message "404 Not Found: Invalid Request" and in the logs I can see that the JAX-WS servlet has initialized because it prints

```
Jan 26, 2013 4:05:38 PM com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate <init>
INFO: WSSERVLET14: JAX-WS servlet initializing
```

However, if I go to http:// localhost:8888/service/EquityService I get the same "404 Not Found: Invalid request" message, and in the logs I can see that nothing has happenned.

Finally, here's the whole log. As far as I can see, everything is doing fine, all the beans are wired...

```
>>> STARTING EMBEDDED JETTY SERVER, PRESS ANY KEY TO STOP
2013-01-26 16:05:32,993 INFO  org.mortbay.log.info:67 - jetty-6.1.25
2013-01-26 16:05:33,332 INFO  /.info:67 - Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
2013-01-26 16:05:33,332 INFO  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext:272 - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
2013-01-26 16:05:33,432 DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment.<init>:114 - Initializing new StandardServletEnvironment
2013-01-26 16:05:33,433 DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment.addLast:104 - Adding [servletConfigInitParams] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2013-01-26 16:05:33,434 DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment.addLast:104 - Adding [servletContextInitParams] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2013-01-26 16:05:33,443 DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment.addLast:104 - Adding [jndiProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2013-01-26 16:05:33,444 DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment.addLast:104 - Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2013-01-26 16:05:33,446 DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment.addLast:104 - Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2013-01-26 16:05:33,446 DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment.<init>:120 - Initialized StandardServletEnvironment with PropertySources [servletConfigInitParams,servletContextInitParams,jndiProperties,systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
2013-01-26 16:05:33,450 INFO  org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.prepareRefresh:500 - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sat Jan 26 16:05:33 CET 2013]; root of context hierarchy
2013-01-26 16:05:33,457 DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment.replace:161 - Replacing [servletContextInitParams] PropertySource with [servletContextInitParams]
2013-01-26 16:05:33,509 DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment.<init>:114 - Initializing new StandardEnvironment
2013-01-26 16:05:33,510 DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment.addLast:104 - Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2013-01-26 16:05:33,510 DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment.addLast:104 - Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2013-01-26 16:05:33,511 DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment.<init>:120 - Initialized StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
2013-01-26 16:05:33,540 DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment.<init>:114 - Initializing new StandardEnvironment
2013-01-26 16:05:33,541 DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment.addLast:104 - Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2013-01-26 16:05:33,542 DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment.addLast:104 - Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2013-01-26 16:05:33,542 DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment.<init>:120 - Initialized StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
2013-01-26 16:05:33,564 INFO  org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.registerDefaultFilters:202 - JSR-250 'javax.annotation.ManagedBean' found and supported for component scanning
2013-01-26 16:05:33,568 INFO  org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions:230 - Successfully resolved class for [com.hello.market.server.MarketServerConfiguration]
2013-01-26 16:05:33,589 DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory:530 - Bean factory for Root WebApplicationContext: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@18b3364: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,marketServerConfiguration]; root of factory hierarchy
2013-01-26 16:05:33,619 DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getSingleton:217 - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor'
2013-01-26 16:05:33,619 DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.createBean:430 - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor'
2013-01-26 16:05:33,666 DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doCreateBean:504 - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor' to allow for resolving potential circular references
2013-01-26 16:05:33,668 DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.createBean:458 - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor'
2013-01-26 16:05:33,749 DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment.addLast:104 - Adding [class path resource [marketservice.properties]] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2013-01-26 16:05:33,761 DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod:270 - Registering bean definition for @Bean method com.hello.market.server.MarketServerConfiguration.equityService()
2013-01-26 16:05:33,762 DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod:270 - Registering bean definition for @Bean method com.hello.market.server.MarketServerConfiguration.equityServiceEndPoint()
2013-01-26 16:05:33,908 DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.enhance:111 - Successfully enhanced com.hello.market.server.MarketServerConfiguration; enhanced class name is: com.hello.market.server.MarketServerConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$f3beb75c
2013-01-26 16:05:33,909 DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses:339 - Replacing bean definition 'marketServerConfiguration' existing class name 'com.hello.market.server.MarketServerConfiguration' with enhanced class name 'com.hello.market.server.MarketServerConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$f3beb75c'
2013-01-26 16:05:33,916 DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getSingleton:217 - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor'
2013-01-26 16:05:33,916 DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.createBean:430 - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor'
2013-01-26 16:05:33,917 DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doCreateBean:504 - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor' to allow for resolving potential circular references
2013-01-26 16:05:33,918 DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.createBean:458 - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor'
2013-01-26 16:05:33,919 DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getSingleton:217 - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor'
2013-01-26 16:05:33,919 DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.createBean:430 - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor'
2013-01-26 16:05:33,920 DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doCreateBean:504 - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor' to allow for resolving potential circular references
2013-01-26 16:05:33,920 DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.createBean:458 - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor'
2013-01-26 16:05:33,921 DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getSingleton:217 - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor'
2013-01-26 16:05:33,921 DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.createBean:430 - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor'
2013-01-26 16:05:33,924 DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doCreateBean:504 - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor' to allow for resolving potential circular references
2013-01-26 16:05:33,924 DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.createBean:458 - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor'
2013-01-26 16:05:33,925 DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getSingleton:217 - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor'
2013-01-26 16:05:33,925 DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.createBean:430 - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor'
2013-01-26 16:05:33,925 DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doCreateBean:504 - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor' to allow for resolving potential circular references
2013-01-26 16:05:33,926 DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.createBean:458 - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor'
2013-01-26 16:05:33,926 DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getSingleton:217 - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0'
2013-01-26 16:05:33,926 DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.createBean:430 - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0'
2013-01-26 16:05:33,926 DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doCreateBean:504 - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0' to allow for resolving potential circular references
2013-01-26 16:05:33,927 DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.createBean:458 - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0'
2013-01-26 16:05:33,930 DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.initMessageSource:799 - Unable to locate MessageSource with name 'messageSource': using default [org.springframework.context.support.DelegatingMessageSource@10721b0]
2013-01-26 16:05:33,934 DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.initApplicationEventMulticaster:823 - Unable to locate ApplicationEventMulticaster with name 'applicationEventMulticaster': using default [org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster@13c7378]
2013-01-26 16:05:33,938 DEBUG org.springframework.ui.context.support.UiApplicationContextUtils.initThemeSource:85 - Unable to locate ThemeSource with name 'themeSource': using default [org.springframework.ui.context.support.ResourceBundleThemeSource@147c1db]
2013-01-26 16:05:33,940 INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons:581 - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@18b3364: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,marketServerConfiguration,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0,equityService,equityServiceEndPoint]; root of factory hierarchy
2013-01-26 16:05:33,940 DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBean:245 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor'
2013-01-26 16:05:33,940 DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBean:245 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor'
2013-01-26 16:05:33,940 DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBean:245 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor'
2013-01-26 16:05:33,940 DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBean:245 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor'
2013-01-26 16:05:33,941 DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBean:245 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor'
2013-01-26 16:05:33,941 DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getSingleton:217 - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'marketServerConfiguration'
2013-01-26 16:05:33,941 DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.createBean:430 - Creating instance of bean 'marketServerConfiguration'
2013-01-26 16:05:33,945 DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doCreateBean:504 - Eagerly caching bean 'marketServerConfiguration' to allow for resolving potential circular references
2013-01-26 16:05:33,958 DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.createBean:458 - Finished creating instance of bean 'marketServerConfiguration'
2013-01-26 16:05:33,958 DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBean:245 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0'
2013-01-26 16:05:33,959 DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getSingleton:217 - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'equityService'
2013-01-26 16:05:33,959 DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.createBean:430 - Creating instance of bean 'equityService'
2013-01-26 16:05:33,965 DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBean:245 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'marketServerConfiguration'
2013-01-26 16:05:34,012 DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doCreateBean:504 - Eagerly caching bean 'equityService' to allow for resolving potential circular references
2013-01-26 16:05:34,015 DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.createBean:458 - Finished creating instance of bean 'equityService'
2013-01-26 16:05:34,015 DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getSingleton:217 - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'equityServiceEndPoint'
2013-01-26 16:05:34,016 DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.createBean:430 - Creating instance of bean 'equityServiceEndPoint'
2013-01-26 16:05:34,016 DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBean:245 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'marketServerConfiguration'
2013-01-26 16:05:34,017 DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext:89 - Current WebApplicationContext is not available for processing of EquityServiceEndPoint: Make sure this class gets constructed in a Spring web application. Proceeding without injection.
2013-01-26 16:05:34,024 DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.<init>:60 - Found injected element on class [com.hello.market.server.service.soap.EquityServiceEndPoint]: AutowiredFieldElement for private com.hello.market.server.service.EquityService com.hello.market.server.service.soap.EquityServiceEndPoint.equityService
2013-01-26 16:05:34,024 DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doCreateBean:504 - Eagerly caching bean 'equityServiceEndPoint' to allow for resolving potential circular references
2013-01-26 16:05:34,028 DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject:85 - Processing injected method of bean 'equityServiceEndPoint': AutowiredFieldElement for private com.hello.market.server.service.EquityService com.hello.market.server.service.soap.EquityServiceEndPoint.equityService
2013-01-26 16:05:34,031 DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBean:245 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'equityService'
2013-01-26 16:05:34,031 DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.registerDependentBeans:424 - Autowiring by type from bean name 'equityServiceEndPoint' to bean named 'equityService'
2013-01-26 16:05:34,034 DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.createBean:458 - Finished creating instance of bean 'equityServiceEndPoint'
2013-01-26 16:05:34,037 DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.initLifecycleProcessor:850 - Unable to locate LifecycleProcessor with name 'lifecycleProcessor': using default [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor@55a338]
2013-01-26 16:05:34,038 DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBean:245 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
2013-01-26 16:05:34,039 DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext:296 - Published root WebApplicationContext as ServletContext attribute with name [org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT]
2013-01-26 16:05:34,039 INFO  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext:301 - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 707 ms
2013-01-26 16:05:34,104 INFO  org.mortbay.log.info:67 - Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:8888
```

Edit: I figured out that if I do the following, the web service will work:

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:/ws-context.xml")
public class MarketServerConfiguration {
```

And in the XML file I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:ws="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core"
       xmlns:wss="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
    http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core
    http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core.xsd
    http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet
    http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd">

    <!-- Temperature Web Service -->
    <wss:binding url="/service/EquityService">
        <wss:service>
            <ws:service bean="#equityServiceEndPoint">
            </ws:service>
        </wss:service>
    </wss:binding>

</beans>
```

Now if I go to localhost:8888/service/EquityService?wsdl I'll get the WSDL printed out for me.

So this is one way to make it work, however, I would like to do it without having to use that extra XML file. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: "When I go to http:// localhost:8888/service" and what if you go to http://localhost:8888/service/ (i.e. with a backslash at the end)

Comment: @ben75 I get the same result if I write service, service/, service/EquityService or service/NonExistantService

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I can help you, but my guess is to use [this lib](https://jax-ws-commons.java.net/spring/) and create your own configuration class, something like @EnableJaxWs. The namespace org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.spring could be a start.

PS.: I give all the credits of this answer to the user (in the portuguese stackoverflow version) [@Chains](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/3180/chains). [See](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31984/inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-beans-spring-em-jax-ws-tomcat-7-webservices-n%C3%A3o-funciona-reto) my question in portuguese, you can use google translate.